# How to save the state of service in android

Tags: android, service

My android service is uploading file on server and it is a sticky service and 90percent is already gets uploaded and in between android system killed that service how will I able to restore the uploading from 90percent onward?Do I have the option to save the state of service in android like we have onSavedStateInstance in Activity and Fragment?

Comment: i don't think you can restore the state of a service, as you are starting it sticky the service will restart if it was killed before the job was done. I guess there should be some communication between service and server while uploading to check what part of file has been uploaded and what is to be uploaded, something like torrent